# excel matching data

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

Hi I have a table with item codes in it eg.

```
    A          B           C           D        E
    Item       500ml       1000ml      2000ml   4000ml                          
1   Juice      8819686     8819687      
2   Vinegar    8813998     8809981     8809982  
3   Ice cream  8805690     8805691     8819815
```

Then I have another list of the above items (I've placed this next to the above table)

```
A                 B
Item              Code
500ml Juice       8819686
1000ml Juice      8819687
500ml Vinegar     8813998
1000ml Vinegar    8809981
2000ml Vinegar    8809982
500ml Ice Cream   8805690
1000ml Ice Cream  8805691
2000ml Ice Cream  8819815
4000ml Ice Cream  8809984
```

I want to know which item code in the list is not appearing in the table above (ie. 8809984 is not in the table).

I tried using =IF(ISNA(MATCH(b2,$B$1:$E$E,0)),"Not Found", "Found"), but not working as it returns "Not Found" for every row.

Thank you

Comment: It is not explicit in the Excel Help file, but I somehow believe that MATCH can find item only from 1-dimensional list of things, dont know that to do with 2-d layout like you have.  i tried with small 2-d range and tried to find one and it failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use Countif for what you describe:

```
=CountIf(Sheet2!$B$1:$E$3,B2)>0
```

You'll get TRUE or FALSE as a result.

Answer (score 0):

how about this way...

`{=sum(if(b2=sheet2!$b$1:$e$3,1,0))}`

this return 0 if there is no b2 in the target area, and 1 (or more if there are dups).  it is array formula so you type everything except {} and then ctrl+alt+enter instead of regular enter.

once you confirmed that the table has unique entry of b2, then you will use following two formula to find index (assuming you do want to know).

`{=sum(if(b2=sheet2!$b$1:$e$3,1,0)*{1,2,3,4})}`

`{=sum(if(b2=sheet2!$b$1:$e$3,1,0)*{1;2;3})}`

top one tells the column, the bottom one tells row.

alternatively you could rearrange the original data somehow, but that's messy too...